How to stop Flask app and subprocesses with Ctrl+C?
Clt+C can be used to stop the Flask app, running on the development server. I would like also to stop the subprocesses that run with the app. With the stop_processes and @app.teardown_appcontext, I have tried to signal the closing of the app and trigger the termination of the subprocesses.
When I press Ctrl+C, the Flask development server stops, however the subprocesses are put to sleep rather than getting termined. Actually, it is the same result as not using the stop_processes function at all.
import flask
import subprocess
import signal
import os

def function1():
    # Create a new subprocess to run 'script1.py', setting it in its own process group
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script1.py'], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    p.wait()
    return p
    

def function2():
    # Create a new subprocess to run 'script2.py', setting it in its own process group
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script2.py'], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    p.wait()
    return p

app = Flask(__name__)

subprocesses = []

@app.route('/process')
def process():

    global subprocesses
    proc1 = function1()
    subprocesses.append(proc1)
    proc2 = function2()
    subprocesses.append(proc2)

    return "Processing completed!"


@app.teardown_appcontext
def stop_subprocesses(exception=None):

    print('Stopping subprocesses ... ')
    global subprocesses
    for p in subprocesses:
        try:
            # Attempt to kill the entire process group associated with each subprocess
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGKILL) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to kill subprocess {p.pid}: {e}")


Do some debugging; try to print the processes and PIDs in the try block. And is it correct that you sometimes write "processes" and sometimes "subprocesses"?

@axolotlKing0722 Fixed the typo: subprocesses. thnx.

@axolotlKing0722  Added print(p.pid) into the try block. When pressing Clt+C nothing gets printed ..

Then it seems that your list is empty. You should check if the processes are really added, and that they're added to the right list.

What is happening in script1.py and script2.py?   Have you verified that function1 ever returns a value?  The call p.wait() with no timeout will do nothing until the subprocess terminates, so it seems likely to me that when the stop_subprocesses teardown function executes, that the subprocesses list is empty.
Add some debug statements to function1, function2 to check what stage they are at, and check the contents of subprocesses before the try block.
